# split a list of overlapping intervals into non overlapping subintervals in a pyspark dataframe and check if values are valid on overlapped intervals

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe that contains the columns `start_time`, `end_time` that define **an interval per row**. It contains as well a column `is_duplicated` set to `True` if one interval is overlapped by at least another interval; set to `False` if not.

There is a column `rate`, and I want to know if there is not different values for a sub-interval (that is overlapped by definition); and if it is the case, I want to **keep the record that contain the latest update** contained in the column `updated_at` as the ground truth.

In the intermediary step, I was thinking to create a column `is_validated` set to:

- `None` when the sub-interval is not overlaped
- `True` when the sub-interval is overlapped by another one containing a different `rate` value and is the last updated
- `False` when the sub-interval is overlapped by another one containing a different `rate` value and is **NOT** the last updated

*Note*: the intermediary step is not mandatory, I provided it just to make the explanation clearer.

**Inputs:**

```py
# So this:
input_rows = [Row(start_time='2018-01-01 00:00:00', end_time='2018-01-04 00:00:00', rate=10, updated_at='2021-02-25 00:00:00'),  # OVERLAP: (1,4) and (2,3) and (3,5) and rate=10/20          
              Row(start_time='2018-01-02 00:00:00', end_time='2018-01-03 00:00:00', rate=10, updated_at='2021-02-25 00:00:00'),  # OVERLAP: full overlap for (2,3) with (1,4)               
              Row(start_time='2018-01-03 00:00:00', end_time='2018-01-05 00:00:00', rate=20, updated_at='2021-02-20 00:00:00'),  # OVERLAP: (3,5) and (1,4) and rate=10/20                          
              Row(start_time='2018-01-06 00:00:00', end_time='2018-01-07 00:00:00', rate=30, updated_at='2021-02-25 00:00:00'),  # NO OVERLAP: hole between (5,6)                                            
              Row(start_time='2018-01-07 00:00:00', end_time='2018-01-08 00:00:00', rate=30, updated_at='2021-02-25 00:00:00')]  # NO OVERLAP

df = spark.createDataFrame(input_rows)
df.show()
>>> +-------------------+-------------------+----+-------------------+
    |         start_time|           end_time|rate|         updated_at|
    +-------------------+-------------------+----+-------------------+
    |2018-01-01 00:00:00|2018-01-04 00:00:00|  10|2021-02-25 00:00:00|
    |2018-01-02 00:00:00|2018-01-03 00:00:00|  10|2021-02-25 00:00:00|
    |2018-01-03 00:00:00|2018-01-05 00:00:00|  20|2021-02-20 00:00:00|
    |2018-01-06 00:00:00|2018-01-07 00:00:00|  30|2021-02-25 00:00:00|
    |2018-01-07 00:00:00|2018-01-08 00:00:00|  30|2021-02-25 00:00:00|
    +-------------------+-------------------+----+-------------------+
# Will become:
tmp_rows = [Row(start_time='2018-01-01 00:00:00', end_time='2018-01-02 00:00:00', rate=10, updated_at='2021-02-25 00:00:00', is_duplicated=False, is_validated=None),
            Row(start_time='2018-01-02 00:00:00', end_time='2018-01-03 00:00:00', rate=10, updated_at='2021-02-25 00:00:00', is_duplicated=True,  is_validated=True),
            Row(start_time='2018-01-02 00:00:00', end_time='2018-01-03 00:00:00', rate=10, updated_at='2021-02-25 00:00:00', is_duplicated=True,  is_validated=True),
            Row(start_time='2018-01-03 00:00:00', end_time='2018-01-04 00:00:00', rate=10, updated_at='2021-02-20 00:00:00', is_duplicated=True,  is_validated=False),
            Row(start_time='2018-01-03 00:00:00', end_time='2018-01-04 00:00:00', rate=20, updated_at='2021-02-25 00:00:00', is_duplicated=True,  is_validated=True),
            Row(start_time='2018-01-04 00:00:00', end_time='2018-01-05 00:00:00', rate=20, updated_at='2021-02-25 00:00:00', is_duplicated=False, is_validated=None),
            Row(start_time='2018-01-06 00:00:00', end_time='2018-01-07 00:00:00', rate=30, updated_at='2021-02-25 00:00:00', is_duplicated=False, is_validated=None),
            Row(start_time='2018-01-07 00:00:00', end_time='2018-01-08 00:00:00', rate=30, updated_at='2021-02-25 00:00:00', is_duplicated=False, is_validated=None)
           ]
tmp_df = spark.createDataFrame(tmp_rows)
tmp_df.show()
>>> 
+-------------------+-------------------+----+-------------------+-------------+------------+
|         start_time|           end_time|rate|         updated_at|is_duplicated|is_validated|
+-------------------+-------------------+----+-------------------+-------------+------------+
|2018-01-01 00:00:00|2018-01-02 00:00:00|  10|2021-02-25 00:00:00|        false|        null|
|2018-01-02 00:00:00|2018-01-03 00:00:00|  10|2021-02-25 00:00:00|         true|        true|
|2018-01-02 00:00:00|2018-01-03 00:00:00|  10|2021-02-25 00:00:00|         true|        true|
|2018-01-03 00:00:00|2018-01-04 00:00:00|  10|2021-02-20 00:00:00|         true|       false|
|2018-01-03 00:00:00|2018-01-04 00:00:00|  20|2021-02-25 00:00:00|         true|        true|
|2018-01-04 00:00:00|2018-01-05 00:00:00|  20|2021-02-25 00:00:00|        false|        null|
|2018-01-06 00:00:00|2018-01-07 00:00:00|  30|2021-02-25 00:00:00|        false|        null|
|2018-01-07 00:00:00|2018-01-08 00:00:00|  30|2021-02-25 00:00:00|        false|        null|
+-------------------+-------------------+----+-------------------+-------------+------------+

# To give you: 
output_rows = [Row(start_time='2018-01-01 00:00:00', end_time='2018-01-02 00:00:00', rate=10),
               Row(start_time='2018-01-02 00:00:00', end_time='2018-01-03 00:00:00', rate=10),
               Row(start_time='2018-01-03 00:00:00', end_time='2018-01-04 00:00:00', rate=20),
               Row(start_time='2018-01-04 00:00:00', end_time='2018-01-05 00:00:00', rate=20),
               Row(start_time='2018-01-06 00:00:00', end_time='2018-01-07 00:00:00', rate=30),
               Row(start_time='2018-01-07 00:00:00', end_time='2018-01-08 00:00:00', rate=30)
              ]
final_df = spark.createDataFrame(output_rows)
final_df.show()
>>> 
+-------------------+-------------------+----+
|         start_time|           end_time|rate|
+-------------------+-------------------+----+
|2018-01-01 00:00:00|2018-01-02 00:00:00|  10|
|2018-01-02 00:00:00|2018-01-03 00:00:00|  10|
|2018-01-03 00:00:00|2018-01-04 00:00:00|  10|
|2018-01-04 00:00:00|2018-01-05 00:00:00|  20|
|2018-01-06 00:00:00|2018-01-07 00:00:00|  30|
|2018-01-07 00:00:00|2018-01-08 00:00:00|  30|
+-------------------+-------------------+----+
```

Comment: shouldn't the third row in the output be 10? it's updated more recently, as in the first row of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Row, SparkSession, SQLContext, Window
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType

spark = (SparkSession.builder 
    .master("local") 
    .appName("Octopus") 
    .config('spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold', -1)
    .getOrCreate())

input_rows = [Row(idx=0, interval_start='2018-01-01 00:00:00', interval_end='2018-01-04 00:00:00', rate=10, updated_at='2021-02-25 00:00:00'),  # OVERLAP: (1,4) and (2,3) and (3,5) and rate=10/20          
              Row(idx=0, interval_start='2018-01-02 00:00:00', interval_end='2018-01-03 00:00:00', rate=10, updated_at='2021-02-25 00:00:00'),  # OVERLAP: full overlap for (2,3) with (1,4)               
              Row(idx=0, interval_start='2018-01-03 00:00:00', interval_end='2018-01-05 00:00:00', rate=20, updated_at='2021-02-20 00:00:00'),  # OVERLAP: (3,5) and (1,4) and rate=10/20                          
              Row(idx=0, interval_start='2018-01-06 00:00:00', interval_end='2018-01-07 00:00:00', rate=30, updated_at='2021-02-25 00:00:00'),  # NO OVERLAP: hole between (5,6)                                            
              Row(idx=0, interval_start='2018-01-07 00:00:00', interval_end='2018-01-08 00:00:00', rate=30, updated_at='2021-02-25 00:00:00')]  # NO OVERLAP


df = spark.createDataFrame(input_rows)
df.show()

# Compute overlapping intervals
sc = spark.sparkContext
sql_context = SQLContext(sc, spark)

def overlap(start_first, end_first, start_second, end_second):
    return ((start_first < start_second < end_first) or (start_first < end_second < end_first)
           or (start_second < start_first < end_second) or (start_second < end_first < end_second))
sql_context.registerFunction('overlap', overlap, BooleanType())

df.registerTempTable("df1")
df.registerTempTable("df2")
df = df.cache()

overlap_df = spark.sql("""
     SELECT df1.idx, df1.interval_start, df1.interval_end, df1.rate AS rate FROM df1 JOIN df2
     ON df1.idx == df2.idx
     WHERE overlap(df1.interval_start, df1.interval_end, df2.interval_start, df2.interval_end)
""")
overlap_df = overlap_df.cache()

# Compute NON overlapping intervals
non_overlap_df = df.join(overlap_df, ['interval_start', 'interval_end'], 'leftanti')

# Stack overlapping points
interval_point = overlap_df.select('interval_start').union(overlap_df.select('interval_end'))
interval_point = interval_point.withColumnRenamed('interval_start', 'p').distinct().sort('p')

# Construct continuous overlapping intervals
w = Window.rowsBetween(1, Window.unboundedFollowing)

interval_point = interval_point.withColumn('interval_end', F.min('p').over(w)).dropna(subset=['p', 'interval_end'])
interval_point = interval_point.withColumnRenamed('p', 'interval_start')

# Stack continuous overlapping intervals and non overlapping intervals
df3 = interval_point.select('interval_start', 'interval_end').union(non_overlap_df.select('interval_start', 'interval_end'))

# Point in interval range join
# https://docs.databricks.com/delta/join-performance/range-join.html
df3.registerTempTable("df3")
df.registerTempTable("df")
sql = """SELECT df3.interval_start, df3.interval_end, df.rate, df.updated_at
         FROM df3 JOIN df ON df3.interval_start BETWEEN df.interval_start and df.interval_end - INTERVAL 1 seconds"""
df4 = spark.sql(sql)
df4.sort('interval_start').show()

# select non overlapped intervals and keep most up to date rate value for overlapping intervals
(df4.groupBy('interval_start', 'interval_end')
    .agg(F.max(F.struct('updated_at', 'rate'))['rate'].alias('rate'))
    .orderBy("interval_start")).show()

+-------------------+-------------------+----+
|     interval_start|       interval_end|rate|
+-------------------+-------------------+----+
|2018-01-01 00:00:00|2018-01-02 00:00:00|  10|
|2018-01-02 00:00:00|2018-01-03 00:00:00|  10|
|2018-01-03 00:00:00|2018-01-04 00:00:00|  10|
|2018-01-04 00:00:00|2018-01-05 00:00:00|  20|
|2018-01-06 00:00:00|2018-01-07 00:00:00|  30|
|2018-01-07 00:00:00|2018-01-08 00:00:00|  30|
+-------------------+-------------------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explode sequences of timestamps, just like your intermediate dataframe, and then group by the start and end times to get the latest rate according to the update time.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

output = df.selectExpr(
    """
    inline(arrays_zip(
        sequence(timestamp(start_time), timestamp(end_time) - interval 1 day, interval 1 day),
        sequence(timestamp(start_time) + interval 1 day, timestamp(end_time), interval 1 day)
    )) as (start_time, end_time)
    """,
    "rate", "updated_at"
).groupBy(
    'start_time', 'end_time'
).agg(
    F.max(F.struct('updated_at', 'rate'))['rate'].alias('rate')
).orderBy("start_time")

output.show()
+-------------------+-------------------+----+
|         start_time|           end_time|rate|
+-------------------+-------------------+----+
|2018-01-01 00:00:00|2018-01-02 00:00:00|  10|
|2018-01-02 00:00:00|2018-01-03 00:00:00|  10|
|2018-01-03 00:00:00|2018-01-04 00:00:00|  10|
|2018-01-04 00:00:00|2018-01-05 00:00:00|  20|
|2018-01-06 00:00:00|2018-01-07 00:00:00|  30|
|2018-01-07 00:00:00|2018-01-08 00:00:00|  30|
+-------------------+-------------------+----+
```

Comment: This is working for this example, but let's say my first interval would be `[1990-01-01 00:00:00, 2018-01-02 00:00:00]`, I don't want to divide into subintervals with a step of 1 day. I think, we should try to split it regarding overlapping intervals?
Another case where it would not work would be if I have minutes and seconds in my interval not set to 0.

Comment: The logic would be, (even if I am not sure how to write it in spark):

- Get the interval start & end date columns
- Stack them into a single column and remove duplicates to get distinct intervals where rate values may differ
- Convert to interval rows by taking the next rows interval point value as the end timestamp of the preceding row
- Join the original table back onto your interval dataset and use a validation function to drop duplicates.
- In this example we will use the max updated_at to filter on most recent records where there are overlaps.

Comment: I think an issue is that some overlapped records spread across multiple rows, like the first three rows... anyway I'll have a think about your logic and how to write it in Spark